# Passing a checkbox state from XML to Java

Tags: java, android, checkbox, crash

I am new to android development, I am trying to pass a checkbox state using findViewById method, but the app gets crashed:

Here is the xml code:

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/toppings_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16sp"
        android:text="Whipped Cream"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:buttonTint="#FFFFFF"
        />
```

and here is the java statement to link this checkbox with java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
CheckBox hasWhippedCream = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.toppings_checkbox);
boolean checked = hasWhippedCream.isChecked();
int quantity = 0;
int pricePerCup = 5;
int toppingPrice = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/**
 * This method is called when the + button is clicked
 */
public void Increment(View view) {
    quantity = quantity + 1;
    displayQuantity(quantity);
}

/**
 * This method is called when the - button is clicked
 */
public void Decrement(View view) {
    quantity = quantity - 1;
    if (quantity < 1) {
        quantity = 1;
    }
    displayQuantity(quantity);
}

/**
 * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
 */
public void submitOrder(View view) {
    displayMessage(createOrderSummary(calculatePrice()));
}

/**
 * Calculates the price of the order.
 */
private int calculatePrice() {

    if (checked = true) {
        toppingPrice = 2;
    } else {
        toppingPrice = 0;
    }
    return quantity * (pricePerCup + toppingPrice);
}

/**
 * This method displays summary of the given order.
 *
 * @param total is the total price of the order.
 *              * @return text summary
 */

private String createOrderSummary(int total) {

    String summary = "Name: Captain Samir\n";
    summary += "Add whipped cream? " + checked + "\n";
    summary += "Quantity: " + quantity + " Cups\n";
    summary += "Total: $" + total + "\n";
    summary += "Thank You!";
    return summary;
}

/**
 * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
 */
private void displayQuantity(int value) {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText("" + value);
}

/**
 * This method displays the given text on the screen.
 */
private void displayMessage(String message) {
    TextView orderSummaryTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.order_summary_text_view);
    orderSummaryTextView.setText(message);
}
}
```

and then I use the variable `checked` through the program. any idea why the app crashes once starts up?

Comment: you should use `findViewById` inside `onCreate`

Comment: but then the variables won't be global, and they won't be readable for other methods in the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CheckBox hasWhippedCream;
    boolean checked;
    int quantity = 0;
    int pricePerCup = 5;
    int toppingPrice = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        hasWhippedCream = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.toppings_checkbox);
        hasWhippedCream.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                checked = isChecked;
            }
        });
        checked = hasWhippedCream.isChecked();
    }

   // rest is the same
}
```

Comment: Well, this helped the app not to crash, but 'checked' variable is not getting updated. it holds the initial value.

Comment: use [setOnCheckedChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener)) for `hasWhippedCream`

Comment: Could you be so kind and explain to me what you did here?

Comment: Code is exactly the same as yours. Difference is that you should use `findViewById` in `onCreate`. After you got reference to your checkbox, you can add listener, so you can know when it was checked (or unchecked). Method `onCheckedChanged` has parameter `isChecked` that is telling you what's the state of your checkbox. And since you need to know what's the state of your checkbox, you store that value in your variable `checked`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your Java code. These are the two mistakes you made:

> - You were supposed to put your executable code inside your onCreate(), not outside of it.
> - You can only monitor for changes on your checkbox by calling onCheckedChangedListener() on it.

**View the code below for the correction:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    boolean checked;


     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     CheckBox hasWhippedCream = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.toppings_checkbox);
     hasWhippedCream.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
             public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             checked = isChecked;
               }
                });


        int quantity = 0;
        int pricePerCup = 5;
        int toppingPrice = 0;

      }

     //Every other part of your code is correct ;-)

      }
```

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!!